# Find the special function form of $\int_0^{+\infty} \left(\sqrt{1+x^4} - x^2\right) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, improper-integrals

I'd like to have an expression of the following integral:
$$\int_0^{+\infty} \left(\sqrt{1+x^4} - x^2\right) dx$$
in terms of some special functions (but not in the form given by [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%5Cinfty%20%28%5Csqrt%7B1%2bx%5E4%7D%20-%20x%5E2%29%20dx&t=crmtb01)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplified answer seems to be :
$$\frac 23K\left(\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$
This means [$\frac 23K\left(\frac 12\right)$ using Alpha's convention](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2/3%2aK%281/2%29) with a rather interesting alternate form :

\begin{align}
\frac{\Gamma\bigl(\frac 14\bigr)^2}{6\;\sqrt{\pi}}&=\frac{\Gamma\bigl(\frac 14\bigr)^2}{6\;\Gamma\bigl(\frac 12\bigr)}\\
&=\frac 16 B\left(\frac 14,\frac 14\right)\\
&=\frac 13 \int_0^\infty \frac {t^{1/4-1}}{\sqrt{1+t}}\;dt\\
\end{align}
with $B(x,y)$ the Euler integral of the first kind ('beta function') and using the [DLMF classical relation $(5.12.3)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12). Setting $x:=t^{1/4}$ should bring you nearer to the initial question...

As noted by O.L. the rewriting of the elliptic integral $K(z)$ in terms of $\Gamma$ function is due to $z=\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}$ being one of the [singular values](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html) of the elliptic integral. It is in fact the first one (see [equation $(11)$ here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticLambdaFunction.html)). Your specific case appears in page $3$ of the original article of [Chowla and Selberg](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1063041/?page=3).

Comment: rhooo, I wish I could upvote once more... btw shouldn't it be $1/\sqrt{2}$ instead of $1/4$ in the 1st answer? Also maybe it could be helpful to mention [singular values of elliptic integrals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html).

Comment: @O.L. Yes you are right of course (the $1/4$ was from squaring two times the initial answer... ;-)).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni thank you.

Comment: You are welcome @qoqosz !

Comment: Thanks for the edit @O.L. (quite a loss of precision while answering here...)